# Text box not showing decimal values jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my jQuery program, I have 3 textboxes. One for `net weight`, one for `rate` and the last readonly text box for `amount`. The amount textbox calculates the product of the rate and the netweight textboxes and displays the result.

```
function amtcal(id)
{    
    var ab="#a"+id;
    var ntwt=parseInt($(ab).val(),10);
    var a="#"+id;
    var rval=parseInt($(a).val(),10);
    var product=rval*ntwt;
    var abc="#aa"+id;
    $(abc).val(product);
}
```

Check out the [working example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JA4s/7/).

The program is working but the error that it is causing is that it ignores the decimal values. If I input the following :-`Nt wt = 5.5 | Rate = 5.2`, the output is given as `25`.

Comment: Don't use parseInt to convert text to numbers unless the result you want really is an integer.

Comment: @Jeffman, make it an answer so that I can vote it as the best one....fair enough

Comment: @BenLind you should remove `parseInt` and instead use `parseFloat`.  Otherwise it will be still `string` datatype.

Comment: Instead of using `parseFloat` or `parseInt`, I suggest to use the unary `+` operator: `+$(ab).val()`. Also, reading the documentation before using a function might be helpful ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @user1671639, I removed parseInt and got the answer no parseFloat requierd

Comment: @FelixKling, Correct, I did that

Comment: @BenLind That is the mistake you're doing.  Incase if you want to add any value withit, it will concatenate instead of doing numeric addition.

Comment: It works without type conversion because you are using multiplication. But as soon as you use addition (`+`), string concatenation would take place instead.

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit? The code should be contained in the question! Without it, the answers don't make sense unless after having a look at the demo. Questions should be self-contained though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `parseInt` to convert text to numbers unless the result you want really is an integer. `parseFloat` or `Number` will do the job here. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove parseint and let it be `rval=$(a).val();`

Comment: While this works in this situation, it can lead to potential bugs later on if addition is also involved. Explicitly converting the value to numbers is the safest approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `parseInt` which will remove all decimal values (making it an int), use `parseFloat` instead which will keep it (thus making it a float).

Comment: I got the answer from @Jeffman. I removed parseInt and the answer is coming perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use this JS:

```
function amtcal(id)
{    
    var ab="#a"+id;
    var ntwt=parseFloat($(ab).val());
    var a="#"+id;
    var rval=parseFloat($(a).val());
    var product=rval*ntwt;
    var abc="#aa"+id;
    $(abc).val(parseFloat(product).toFixed(2));
}
```

Here `.toFixed()` is used to show 2 digits after decimal point.

Answer (score -1):

I have update jQuery code and updated in jsfiddle.
Here is updated jQuery.

```
function amtcal(id){
    var ab="#a"+id;
    var ntwt=$(ab).val();
    var a="#"+id;
    var rval=$(a).val();
    var product=rval*ntwt;
    var abc="#aa"+id;
   $(abc).val(product);
}
```